# Speed up powershell move-item command

Tags: windows, powershell

I've been using the basic "Move-Item -path G:\folder* -destination K:\folder"

However, I have about 20,000 folders, and about 15 million files. This has been 2 days and so far only a few thousand folders (and the content inside) has been moved. The reason I used this command over the typical move feature in Windows Explorer is that I have files with filenames that are VERY long. I've tried expanding the file name limit in Windows, but it still hits a limit when 'moving' using Windows Explorer. It only seems to work (or appears to work without error) with powershell.

Is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use robocopy with it's `/MT:x` parameter.  `/MT` is for multi-threading.  Also, it doesn't suffer the character limits you find in the Windows interface.  In fact you'll find many robocopy examples on the web just to find long file names.  You don't have to abandon the work you've already done.  Robocopy is incremental it won't recopy a file that hasn't changed.  A command might look something like:

```
Robocopy.exe <SourceFolder> <DestinationFolder> /E /MT:20 /Log:c:\temp\Robolog.log
```

Or your example:

```
Robocopy.exe "G:\folder" "K:\folder" /E /MT:20
```

> Note/Update: Changed from `/MIR` to `/E` because some files would have already been moved due to prior work.

This command will effectively run 20 Robocopy.exe processes cooperating to copy the data.

Robocopy has many parameters, so the above example is my guess to what you need. `/E` means Copy all subfolders including empty ones and will copy all files folders below the source director. Using the `/Log` or `/Log+` will send the output to a file instead of the screen. In my experience saving the program from screen echoing speeds things up.  That said, I have had mixed results in the log file itself when using `/MT:x`.  However, the mission here is to get the data over much more quickly...

Incidentally `/TEE` would allow you to send output to both the screen and log.

Also since it's incremental you can rerun afterward perhaps with different logging and threading options to confirm everything copied.  If you elect not to use `/MOVE` ... You can even craft a command to purge the source files and folders when done.

```
RoboCopy.exe <EmptyDirectory> <OriginalSourceDirectory> /MIR
```

Always make sure you test with the `/L` parameter before executing.  `/L` is list mode so it will show or log what will happen without copying or deleting anything.

Use Robocopy.exe /? for the full documentation.

Comment: I tried "Robocopy.exe G:\Folder K:\Folder /MOVE /MT:20 /Log:c:\temp\Robolog.log"

But got all errors saying "extra dir" Tried searching for a solution but can't seem tp nail it down. But it seems it doesn't want to copy since some files are in dest but not source?

Comment: Looking into the MIR command, it seems to be an "/e + /purge" command. however, looking at purge it says "delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source" Doesn't that mean that something will get lost along the way? 

I'm looking to 100% move all folders and content from G:\ to K:\ with the assumption that there are a few thousand files and folders already in K from the previous powershell command

Comment: Yes considering you started with a move.  You can use `/E` to copy without purging.

Comment: You were right. I changed the directory used (went one level up) and it worked! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Try `Start-BitsTransfer`, here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/start-bitstransfer?view=win10-ps).

Comment: BITS transfer is pretty neat. I wonder how it stacks up performance-wise vs robocopy over smb.

Comment: I did not do benchmark speed-wise, but just feel it is more efficient. The major benefit for me is that it can run in background, and I can resume (`Resume-Bitstransfer`) after session timeout or network failure, while previously the foreground copy failed many times, so it is more suitable for copying large number of files or large files.